# Detox - DetoxManager can not find kotlin/jvm/functions/Function1 at runtime

Tags: android, react-native, kotlin, jvm, detox

To reproduce the issue I'm facing I used the `react-native` example project [demo-react-native](https://github.com/wix/Detox/tree/master/examples/demo-react-native) from `Detox.

After installing the packages with `yarn` I executed the 2 commands to run the test:

1) `cd android && ./gradlew assembleRelease assembleAndroidTest -DtestBuildType=release && cd ..`

2) `npx detox test -l error --configuration android.emu.release`

So far everything works as expected but as soon I add the dependency of the Kotlin standard library in the `android/app/build.gradle` file like that

```
dependencies {
  ...
  androidTestImplementation('com.wix:detox:+')
  implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.3.71" // <-- line added
}
```

and run the 2 steps again I get the following error

```
04-05 20:21:06.709 16552 16615 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: com.wix.detox.manager
04-05 20:21:06.709 16552 16615 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.test.app, PID: 16552
04-05 20:21:06.709 16552 16615 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lkotlin/jvm/functions/Function1;
04-05 20:21:06.709 16552 16615 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.wix.detox.Detox$1.run(Detox.java:134)
04-05 20:21:06.709 16552 16615 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
04-05 20:21:06.709 16552 16615 E AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "kotlin.jvm.functions.Function1" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/android.test.runner.jar", zip file "/system/framework/android.test.mock.jar", zip file "/data/app/com.test.app.test-xbA2GW9WwS_BxzRNPa2waQ==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.test.app-g_-tD026mxddTh82TmdYGg==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.test.app.test-xbA2GW9WwS_BxzRNPa2waQ==/lib/x86, /data/app/com.test.app-g_-tD026mxddTh82TmdYGg==/lib/x86, /data/app/com.test.app.test-xbA2GW9WwS_BxzRNPa2waQ==/base.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/com.test.app-g_-tD026mxddTh82TmdYGg==/base.apk!/lib/x86, /system/lib]]
04-05 20:21:06.709 16552 16615 E AndroidRuntime:    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
04-05 20:21:06.709 16552 16615 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
04-05 20:21:06.709 16552 16615 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
```

I have tried to load the `JVM` plugin in the `android/build.gradle` file as described [here](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm) but it doesn't help.

What else can I do to make `org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm` work in that project?

Thank you in advance.

#### Edit 1

I added `kotlin.jvm.functions.Function1` to the `MainApplication.java` to test whether the `Kotlin JVM` is actually accessible by the project by adding the following code

```
...
import kotlin.jvm.functions.Function0;
import kotlin.jvm.functions.Function1;

public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {
    private Function1<Throwable, String> errorParseFn = new Function1<Throwable, String>() {
        @Override
        public String invoke(Throwable t) {
            return Log.getStackTraceString(t);
        }
    };

    ...

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        SoLoader.init(this, /* native exopackage */ false);
        Log.d("@@@@@@", "onCreate");
        Log.d("@@@@@@", errorParseFn.invoke(new Exception("Test Exception message")));
    }
}
```

after I ran `npx detox test -l error --configuration android.emu.release` once again I could see the logs in the console.

```
04-06 21:24:06.715 23836 23836 D @@@@@@  : onCreate
04-06 21:24:06.716 23836 23836 D @@@@@@  : java.lang.Exception: Test Exception message
```

That means that the app itself has access to the `kotlin.jvm`, which means the `gradle` setup is correct.

Has anyone an idea how `DetoxManager.java` can access the `Kotlin JVM` at **runtime**?

Comment: What happens when you try to use `kotlin-stdlib-jdk8` explicitly instead of just `kotlin-stdlib`?

Comment: Hi @d4vidi, I have switched the standard lib to `implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.3.71" but that didn't help. I have also added an `Edit 1` section to my initial question that describes a test I conducted. Please have a look.

Comment: I too stuck at the same issue. @ThomasDittmar did you get the solution for it ?

Comment: Yes I have. I didn’t have time to post a solution. I will do that within the next hour.

Comment: @shaktisinghmoyal I posted the solution. Did you check it out?

Comment: @ThomasDittmar yes i checked it out. I was able to fix it by using your solution. However i thought i should not avoid obfuscation. hence i came up with slight modification in proguard to fix it. Have a look at my solution which i have pasted as an answer

Answer (score 2):

I finally have time to post the solution.

After researching the meaning of the log

```
Note: kotlin.jvm.internal.Reflection: can't find dynamically referenced class kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.ReflectionFactoryImpl
Note: kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.DebugMetadataKt accesses a declared field 'label' dynamically
...
Note: there were 1 references to unknown classes.
      You should check your configuration for typos.
      (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unknownclass)
```

I found that `Proguard` is removing `Kotlin` dependencies.

To prove the hypothesis I commented out the lines regarding proguard in the `app/build.gradle` of the [demo-react-native](https://github.com/wix/Detox/blob/master/examples/demo-react-native/android/app/build.gradle#L50-L52)

```
buildTypes {
  release {
    // minifyEnabled true
    // proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    // proguardFile "${rootProject.projectDir}/../node_modules/detox/android/detox/proguard-rules-app.pro"

    signingConfig signingConfigs.release
  }
}
```

and it worked as expected.

That meant I had to create my own `buildType` just for the *E2E* test and include `proguard` only for the *release build*

```
...
signingConfigs {
  e2e_release {
    storeFile file("keystore.e2e.jks")
    storePassword "987654321"
    keyAlias "e2e_key"
    keyPassword "987654321"
  }
  release {
    storeFile file("keystore.jks")
    storePassword "12345678"
    keyAlias "key0"
    keyPassword "12345678"
  }
buildTypes {
  e2eRelease {
    initWith release
    matchingFallbacks = ['release']
    signingConfig signingConfigs.e2e_release
  }
  release{}
  if(gradle.startParameter.taskNames.contains("assembleRelease")) {
    minifyEnabled true
    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    proguardFile "${rootProject.projectDir}/../node_modules/detox/android/detox/proguard-rules-app.pro"
    signingConfig signingConfigs.release
  }
}
```

The only thing left was to adjust the path and build command in the `package.json` file like that

```
"android.emu.e2e": {
  "binaryPath": "android/app/build/outputs/apk/e2eRelease/app-e2eRelease.apk",
  "build": "cd android && RN_SRC_EXT=e2e.js ./gradlew app:assembleE2ERelease  app:assembleE2EReleaseAndroidTest -DtestBuildType=e2eRelease -x bundleE2eReleaseJsAndAssets && cd ..",
  "type": "android.emulator",
  "device": {
    "avdName": "Nexus_6P_API_28"
  }
}
```

Please note, the folder `outputs/apk/e2eRelease` have to be created manually before running `./gradlew assembleE2ERelease assembleE2EReleaseAndroidTest -DtestBuildType=e2eRelease`

This works very well but let me know if there is a better solution.

Cheers

Comment: What strikes me odd is that Detox' demo app (as you linked it) _does_ have Proguard definitions in place - similar to yours, and yet it works well (FunctionX classes do not get dropped). In fact, it's no accident that I've created that setup in the first place...
In any case, I've once published a blogpost describing all these configuration quirks, hope it could be of use here: https://medium.com/wix-engineering/configuring-proguard-for-android-instrumentation-tests-120d58cba155

Answer (score 2):

I was able to mitigate the same  errors by adding the following configuratuon in proguard file.

```
-dontobfuscate



-keep class kotlin.** { *; }

-keep class kotlin.Metadata { *; }

-dontwarn kotlin.**
```

Comment: That also means that **Proguard** is not used in `release` mode for the `Kotlin` files, right?

Comment: It means just ommiting out these from proguard. As i am using a react native. I dont have any code in kotlin. It is just detox which has some portion of code in kotlin.  Hence adding this configuration in proguard make no difference to my actual product. You can choose what suits you well

Comment: But in the actual `release` (**Production App**) you want ProGuard to delete the `Kotlin` files for security reasons. Have a look here https://proandroiddev.com/is-your-kotlin-code-really-obfuscated-a36abf033dde

Comment: I use RN as well. They are quite a few libraries that use `Kotlin` under the hood. You probably have `Kotlin` code somewhere. Hence, why it didn't build.

Comment: Can this not be minimized to just have `-keep class kotlin.jvm.functions.** { *; }` and `-keep class kotlin.Unit { *; }`? If so, lmk and I'll add this to Detox' own proguard settings (so you won't have to).

Comment: @d4vidi i tried using which you have suggested. I got following errors and tests failed before even start. Hence i reverted to the changes i suggested.                                           
                                                                                                                 
    `EXCEPTION: com.wix.detox.manager
    Process: com.aasaanjobs.employee.aasaanjobsemployee, PID: 7447
 java.lang.RuntimeException: waited a whole minute for the new RN-context at com.wix.detox.reactnative.ReactNativeLoadingMonitor.awaitNewRNContext(ReactNativeLoadingMonitor.kt:56)`

Comment: That sounds like a secondary error, please check that there are no preliminary errors regarding missing classes, fields etc.

Comment: @shaktisinghmoyal In Detox 17.3.2, we've allowed for a manual configuration of longer loading timeouts: https://github.com/wix/Detox/releases/tag/17.3.2. Please try to restore the `-keep`'s I suggested with Detox 17.3.2, alongside a configuration of long timeout (default is 60sec) using `Detox.runTests(rule, config)`. Thanks!